# Using slightly different voltage battery for my laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, voltage

I’ve an acer laptop (Acer aspire e15) and it’s battery was blown up and doesn’t work anymore. So I ordered a new battery off amazon with correct voltage which was 11.1V as it was written on the battery. But now I got the battery but it’s not the voltage I ordered, it’s 10.95V. Which is very close to what I ordered but not exactly the same, and I don’t know why.

Now can I use this on my laptop without it blowing up or something like that? Everything about the battery is correct except for the voltage (10.95 vs 11.1V), I guess it’s just for an older version of the laptop which may have been a little different.
I really want to know if this works or not, because I cannot return the battery and it cost me too much as a student (81$). Thanks.

Comment: Is the battery you bought labeled "Acer" or is it 3rd-party/OEM/off-brand?  A battery voltage difference of less than 1.5% is probably inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

Modern laptop batteries are made up of multiple cells of Lithium Ion batteries.

According to [batteryuniversity.com](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/confusion_with_voltages)

> The nominal voltage of lithium-ion is 3.60V/cell. Some cell
>   manufacturers mark their Li-ion as 3.70V/cell or higher. This offers a
>   marketing advantage because the higher voltage boosts the watt-hours
>   on paper (voltage multiplied by current equals watts). The 3.70V/cell
>   rating also creates unfamiliar references of 11.1V and 14.8V when
>   connecting three and four cells in series rather than the more
>   familiar 10.80V and 14.40V respectively. Equipment manufacturers
>   adhere to the nominal cell voltage of 3.60V for most Li-ion systems as
>   a power source.

All lithium ion batteries have the same nominal voltage. Any differences are labeling errors or deliberate manipulation. Certain modifications to the lithium ion chemistry can change the nominal voltage, but doing so would make the battery incompatible with the equipment it was designed to operate with. The difference in labeling you see is insignificant.

Comment: Also note that the nominal voltage is measured while battery is being drained from full charge (4.2V) to cut off voltage (3.0V) by 0.5C and the nominal voltage is the voltage between the terminals at the time the battery has the half of its energy. That means, whether the nominal voltage is 3.6V or 3.7V (or 3.9V or 3.1V, it doesn't matter, really), the exact parameter that has to be taken into account is the maximum voltage of the cells for that chemistry as for the burnout case. Nominal voltages may slightly vary due to internal resistance while the maximum cut off voltage stays intact.